# django - images system like wordpress

Tags: python, django, wordpress, image

I am impressed with how wordpress handle the images (where user can upload and insert images into post). I want to make this feature to able applied in django. How do I achieve it?

Basically I have two models :

1.post - for writing the content

2.media - for uploading images/files

But in the **post** model I would like to able insert the images from the **media** model in the textField().  For the textField I am using django-tinymce for rich text context with filebrowser integration. So, better use the Image button to upload/insert image to/from **media** model.

Also the user only allow to browse the images that he/she uploaded in the filebrowser.

Lastly beside in the admin, this feature also need to work in frontend.

So is this possible?

Comment: [django-filebrowser](https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-filebrowser) plugin is what you need. Or write all the JS yourself.

Comment: Your question does not really depends on Django being the backend framework. Most of what you are asking is frontend stuff, thus Javascript stuff. You may be able to extend/configure TinyMCE to handle image uploads. Server side (Django side), you just need to store them and return the public URL.